# How can i find the relevance of a page?

Tags: data-mining, information-retrieval, relevance

Say I have some features of a person and then i perform google search.
A list of results display I want to mine those results and check how the contents of those results are relevant to that particular person.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform a Google search, the relevancy is best computed using

```
relevancy = cos(x) * (sqrt(x) + atan2(x,y)) * sin(0)
```

This is the universal formula for relevancy. You can apply it to people or to questions on SO.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this formula?